# Computations of Bredon homology of $S(1+\sigma)$ with Universal Coefficient S.S

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, equivariant-cohomology

What I am trying to do is to compute $\mathbb{Z}$-graded Bredon homology of $S(1+\sigma)$ over $Q\times\Sigma_2$, where

- $Q$ is a cyclic group of order 2
- $\sigma$ is its real sign representation
- $\Sigma_2$ is acting on $S(1+\sigma)$ by antipodal action.

In particular, different notation for a cyclic group of order 2 is used to emphasize different actions. To make notation more legible, let's put $S:=S(1+\sigma)$. Its Bredon homology with $\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2$ coefficients is given by $H^{Q\times\Sigma_2}_0(S;\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2)=\mathbb{F}_2\oplus\mathbb{F}_2$ and $H^{Q\times\Sigma_2}_1(S;\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2)=\mathbb{F}_2$.

I may compute this homology also by the Universal Coefficient Spectral Sequence, which is given by 
$$
E^2_{p,q}=Tor^{\mathcal{O}_{Q\times\Sigma_2}}_p\left(H_q(S^\bullet),\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2\right)\Rightarrow H^{Q\times\Sigma_2}_{p+q}(S;\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2)
$$

Singular homology here is taken with integral coefficients. (Using this method is a little bit of overkill, but this is supposed to be a toy example for further calculations).

I have inputs of the $E^2$ page computed - they are given by:
$$
Tor_i(H_0(S^\bullet),\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{F}_2\oplus\mathbb{F}_2 & i=0 \\
\mathbb{F}_2 & i=1 \\
\mathbb{F}_2^{i-1} & i>1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and

$$
Tor_i(H_1(S^\bullet),\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2)=
\mathbb{F}_2^{i+1}
$$
for $i\geq 0$. Everything else vanish.

So I have my second page of the spectral sequence, but I am struggling with identifying the differentials. From the calculations "by hand" I see that they are supposed to be isomorphisms. But I have got no clue how to show that.

Could anybody give me a hand on that?

Comment: The best I can suggest is that, if you give $S$ an equivariant cell structure, it only has nonzero cells in dimensions $0$ and $1$, so there is an exact sequence $$0 \to H_1(S) \to C_1(S) \to C_0(S) \to H_0(S) \to 0.$$ You can deduce (using long exact sequences or spectral sequences) that there is a map $Tor_{i+2}(H_0(S),M) \to Tor_i(H_1(S),M)$, induced by cap product with this Yoneda extension. The middle two terms are projective Mackey functors, so this cap is an isomorphism for large enough $i$. But perhaps this is just shuttling around information you already know...

Comment: Well, it's exactly opposite :) How you can deduce existence of these maps?

Comment: Which maps? The ones in the exact sequence above, or the ones on Tor? (Or both?)

Comment: The ones on Tor, I can see the ones in the exact sequence.

Comment: Ok, I have Weibel's Homological Algebra in front of me, I suppose I should be able to deduce these maps - but how to see that they are the ones fitting in the spectral sequence?

Comment: If you un-splice into short exact sequences $0 \to H_1(S) \to C_1(S) \to B_0(S) \to 0$ and $0 \to B_0(S) \to C_0(S) \to H_0(S) \to 0$ then the map on $Tor$ is just applying the associated connecting homomorphisms twice.

Comment: So far as the spectral sequence goes, you need a specific construction of the universal coefficient spectral sequence to give a precise argument of how the differentials happen. One construction is exactly that you filter $C_\bullet(S)$ by "connective covers" and then put together the long exact sequences on $Tor$ precisely so that the differentials are these iterative connecting homomorphisms, which makes the above description easier -- but a different construction of the spectral sequence might make it harder. Do you have a particular construction in mind?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about construction similar to one given in Weibel's book - i.e. we choose a projective resolution $P_\bullet$ of $\underline{\mathbb{F}}_2$, we form a double complex by tensoring with $C_\bullet(S^\bullet)$ and filter it by rows and by columns. However, I was struggling wth getting anything out of this construction. It seems that you have better way of constructing it - could you give me any references?

Comment: In this case, since it comes from a double complex the d_2 differential is explicit: given an element, lift it to a representing cycle, apply the horizontal differential, observe that it lifts along the vertical differential, and apply the horizontal differential to that.

Comment: So start with an element in $Tor_{i+2}(H_0(S),M)$, represented by an element in $H_0(S) \square P_{i+2}$. This element is represented by lifting to some element in $C_0(S) \square P_{i+2}$. The horizontal boundary in $C_0(S) \square P_{i+1}$ has image zero in $H_0(S) \square P_{i+1}$, so (by the 4-term exact sequence, box-product with $P_{i+1}$) it lifts to an element in $C_1(S) \square P_{i+1}$. Applying the horizontal boundary map gives us an element in $C_1(S) \square P_i$ whose vertical differential is zero, so it actually comes from $H_1(S) \square P_i$.

Comment: However, this has precisely the same effect as the double application of the connecting homomorphism that I mentioned earlier, except that we have omitted some unnecessary steps (pushing down to $B_0(S) \square P_{i+1}$ and then immediately lifting back to $C_1(S) \square P_{i+1}$).

Comment: (I believe that this expression for the $d_2$-differential in a double complex is explicit in Weibel, but I do not know where.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks like very nice solution to my problem!